# A word for "from one day in a month until the same day in the next"

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Is there a word that can help me describe a period that isn't exactly a calendar month, but is meant to serve as a month regarding, say, a service or rental period?

For example - if my rental starts on the 15th of January, I am being billed for Jan 15 - Feb 14, then Feb 15 thru Mar 14,  and so on.

> Your contract isn't for complete months, rather for ________________.

What can I call these periods? I need "month" to be used strictly for calendar months. **OR** - say I call January a *Calendar Month*, this period would be a ___________ *Month*?

If I was talking about days, I could say *24 hours*, but I can't do something similar here because there aren't always 30 days in these "months".

Comment: Why are you opposed to just calling it a month? It technically is a rental month. A month isn't always 30 days.

Comment: @Hank - I addressed your question in an edit I just made. If I'm straying from the accepted months and their respective length, I need to be very specific describing the other idea, I don't want to be misleading in my documentation.

Comment: It's my understanding that *month* would still be the best to describe a period from Jan 15th - Feb 14th. That's what is always used in the contracts I sign (leases, memberships, etc.), even though they don't span from the first to the last day in one specific month. Although, if you are looking to be legally specific for contract purposes, you may want to post in [law.stackexchange.com](http://law.stackexchange.com), as it may be more suitable to this situation.

Comment: The stretch from Jan 15-Feb 14 is exactly one month, as is the stretch from Feb 15-Mar 14, even though one of them is 31 days and one is 28 days.  The contract does not begin on the start of a month, but its duration is for whole-month periods.

Comment: @Hellion - thank you, but I need another word. I am using both calendar months and these kinds of months - so I need a way to differentiate. Maybe the edit I made in the question will help clarify this.

Comment: @DAE I do see what you're trying to do but you're reserving the only word to describe this by using it to describe something that ***calendar month*** can describe. Why do you have to use *month* to describe a *calendar month*?

Comment: Perhaps you could refer to your periods as "fiscal months".  If you google it the most common result refers to the so-called "4-4-5" month arrangement, but the point is that a fiscal month can start and end on other dates than the "calendar start/end" dates.

Comment: Alternatively, something like "month-long billing periods" would fit your example sentence.

Comment: @Hank - because month is commonly used and interpreted as Jan, Feb, etc. I need to be very clear and don't want to cause confusion. If I do depart from the conventional meaning then I need some other qualifying word.

Comment: @DAE That's where I disagree. A *calendar month* is specific type of *month*-long period. If it wasn't, it would just be called *month* and *calendar month* wouldn't exist. I'm not trying to be extremely argumentative but, if you really are writing a contract, you need to be literal, based on facts and definitions, and not account for what you or someone else may think a month is. Just because someone hears month and thinks a calendar month doesn't mean you can use month in a contract and it explicitly mean calendar month. I think you should only use calendar month to describe calendar month.

Comment: I'd call it "billing month".

Comment: Not saying you should use *month*, as others have suggested plenty of alternatives. Just making sure you don't falsely use a vague *month* to describe something more specific, like a *calendar month*.

Comment: Your rentals are for *one month periods*. The contract could state “This rental contract is for the one month period beginning January 15, 2017 and ending February 14, 2017.  for example.

Comment: Why can you not state that rental periods are calendar monthly periods and payment is due on the same day each month?

Comment: @Chris To me, that would imply that the rental period is from 1st of the calendar month to the last day of the same calendar month (e.g. 1st - 31st Jan; 1st to 30th April; etc.) irrespective of on which day of the month the rental was paid.

Comment: If it's in any kind of contract, then *define* the term somewhere in the contract, and use it accordingly.  Arguably, this is a legal question.

Answer (score 1):

I would say **solar month** if I wanted to be absolutely certain that "month" is interpreted as a period of a certain amount of days and hours.

However, **calendar month** is technically the term for what you describe, although someone may misinterpret as "January", "February" and so on:

> The period of duration from the same date of one month to the same date of the next month, and thus can be 28, 29 during a leap year, 30 or 31 days long. For example the duration from 21st January to 20th February.

(from https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/calendar_month ).

Comment: upvote for the interesting and surprising wiktionary entry! I really think Calendar Month implies the "misinterpreted" meaning though. But its hard to argue...

Answer (score 0):

Consider using 'elapsed month'.

[Elapse](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/elapse) (MW, intransitive verb)

> pass, go by "four years elapsed before he returned"

In your case:

> Your contract isn't for calendar months, but rather for elapsed months (i.e. the 15th of January to the 14th of February)